# How to dynamically access/overwrite a field in a class using a variable?

Tags: python, python-3.x, class

I have a class where I would like to overwrite one instance with another (with the exception of one field). My approach was something along the lines of this:

```py
for key in my_class_instance_1.__dict__.keys():
    if key != "key_i_dont_want_to_overwrite":
        my_class_instance_1[key] = my_class_instance_2[key]
```

The problem is that I get the error `TypeError: 'MyClass' object is not subscriptable`.

I am also apparently unable to access the instance like this: `my_class_instance_1.f"{key}"`.

I don't know how to dynamically access a key on a class for the purpose of overwriting it. I know that I can use `getattr(my_class_instance_2, key)` in order to access the value, but this will not help me overwrite the value on `my_class_instance_1`.

Comment: Use `getattr()`'s companion function, `setattr()`

Comment: [setattr][1]


  [1]: https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#setattr

Comment: That seems to have done the trick, thanks @kindall and @ skullgoblet1089

Answer (score 4):

Thanks to @kindall's and @skullgoblet1089's responses I was able to figure this out, but for anyone else that has this problem, let me show you the working code:

```py
for key in my_class_instance_1.__dict__.keys():
    if key != "key_i_dont_want_to_overwrite":
        val = getattr(my_class_instance_2, key)  # the new value
        setattr(my_class_instance_1, key, val)  # overwriting the old value
```

There is a sibling function to `getattr()` called `setattr()` which allows you to set an attribute.